# How do I grant permission to view Execution Logs

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, permissions

I have a project in Google Apps Script. I gave my co-worker "Editor" permissions. Now he sees the list of executions. but when he clicks on a specific line he gets the following message:

> You do not have access to logs
>
> Request permission from the project owner to view logs.

How can I allow him full control and access to everything he might need in the Scripting Console?

Enable Chrome V8 runtime is enabled

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details about the script? I just made a new project, with a simple function that just logged something to the console, and shared it with another user and they can see the executions. Can you maybe say what services your script uses, if its deployed, if the function is a `doGet` `doPost` or trigger or anything else? Are you able to test with a brand new project too?

Comment: Hi. The executions he can see, no problem. The issue is when he clicks on a execution to see the logs. That's when he gets the error message. Thanks!

Comment: Right, the user I shared it with can see the messages no problem. That is, they can see the logs. There is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tester/collaborator to be able to view the log entries for a project for which they are not the owner do the following:

- Go to the GCP project
- Click on IAM in the dashboard
- Click on Grant Access
- Enter the user email in the New principals field
- Enter **Basic/Viewer** in the Select a role field

This should allow the user to view the log entries in both the Google Apps Script Project Logs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by creating an [IAM user](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs) for the person who needed it in the GCP project associated with my script. Note that my script is a [container bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), bound to a google sheet that I own, and the user in question is an editor on the google sheet. While this user was able to see and edit my apps script project, they were not able to view the execution logs until I followed the below steps.

Steps:

1. If you haven't already, [create a GCP project for your script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/07/05/linking-cloud-platform-project-to-google-apps-script-project/)
2. From your Apps Script project page, click `Project Settings` gear icon
3. Under the header `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project`, click the hyperlink on the ID of your GCP project number
4. On your GCP project page, go to Dashboard > Project Info > Add people to this project
5. Create an IAM user for the email that you want to be able to view execution logs. I assigned editor privileges.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a Google Cloud Platform Project.

You need to ask the owner to give you permission in IAM.

Comment: For me it says it's the "Default" project which doesn't exist in GCP. Funny thing is that it's my Script, as in "Owner: me".

Comment: Which permission should be given in IAM?